# How to restore my Ubuntu 18.04 to a state from a week ago?

Tags: backup, restore

I have tried looking this up on the web but ran into many discussions telling me to "install" a backup program, such as Timeshift. I am way past that! My system asks me to backup perhaps once per week. I guess this is the default.  I want to restore the entire hard drive as it was a week or two ago.

How do I know which backup program is running? Are there instructions for the DEFAULT backup program that runs for me to restore? Again, I don't want the newest backup, I want a back from a week or two ago. And how can I tell if it will restore EVERYTHING?

Comment: Most backup programs do not do a full disk backup.  Unless you have a full disk backup of your entire system from a week ago chances are you can't.  And there is by default no backup solution installed in Ubuntu systems unless you install one yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I must have installed backup then. I see it is only backing up my /var/www/ directory which is where all of my development work is done anyway. What is happening when I try to start up my app I get a message "Cannot locate javascript file: assets/themes/default/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js.". I am not sure where assets/themes.. is. Can I get a copy of jquery-1.9.1.min.js and just put it back? I could restore var/www from last week. When I run restore it asks what file to restore from. I see files dates dec 26 ending in difftar.gpg, manifest.gpg, and sigtar.gpg. Which of these 3 do I restore?